# Could someone explain to me what this line of PHP/SQL is trying to accomplish

Tags: php, postgresql

I was asked to fix a problem with the website of a customer, and I think this line is at least partly responsible for the error:

```
$SQL="select 'SC' ||substr(10000+max(to_number(secondid, '99G999D9S'))+1,2,4) from table";
```

I can't quite tell what this line above is trying to accomplish, whether it's just a bad piece of code that wasn't written correctly or something important and well thought out. I know that substr is a PHP function, and yet, it's in the double quotes, so it's part of the query, and I also know that max and to_number are postgresql functions.
I have no idea what SC is, it isn't a field in the table. If I run this query by itself:

```
SELECT 'SC' FROM table;
```

I get a ?column?(of unknown type), and the number of rows is one greater than the number of rows in the table (or the same if you include the empty row at the end of each table). Each row simply states holds SC.
What's the point of the || operator? If I recall correctly, that is an OR operator, so how does the query decide what it wants to select?

Sorry for the trouble, thanks for your time.

Comment: In SQL, `||` is the concatenation operator. So you're concatanating "SC" with the result of `substr(10000+max(to_number(secondid, '99G999D9S'))+1,2,4)`. `substr` is referring to the postgresql function, not the PHP one. For more info see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is taking the value of field `secondid`, converts it to numerical, using `99G999D9S`, then finds the max of these values across the table, add 10000 and 1 to it; converts the result to string, takes the substring 4-char long starting from the second character;  finally appends it string 'SC' and returns to you.  For a table where `secondid` column is defined and is formatted accordingly, you will get exactly 1 result back.  If this column is not defined or is formatted differently, you'll get an error.

`||` operator is the concatenation in SQL.

Comment: Oh, I see, but for some reason, the query gives me an error, and it probably worked before. The query is part of a file that adds a new product into the database, and if I add the product, then a PHP pg_query error pops up, but the product is added, though, it is added without a secondid field. Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: I see, well, thanks for all the help, for some reason, the error states that the function substr(numeric, integer, integer) does not exist, in the HINT, it adds that you might need to add explicit type casts. to_number is a typecast, right?

Comment: This is simple.  All you need to do then is to change `substr(10000+max(to_number(secondid, '99G999D9S'))+1,2,4)` to `substr((10000+max(to_number(secondid, '99G999D9S'))+1)::varchar,2,4)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the ::varchar bit seemed to do the trick. So, this is an explicit cast, eh.  For future note though, I got this error after I did as you suggested: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" ` The fix for this was just going back and adding a value for the blank values of secondid, just mentioning it in case someone else runs into it.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.  In general though, it's not the best idea to  determine the next in this way.  You'd be much better off by creating a sequence starting with whatever the right level is, then using the next value form this sequence to set into the id field.  It's much faster and is less prone to errors.

Answer (score 4):

### Working in-side out:

#### *The original statement:*

`$SQL="select 'SC' ||substr(10000+max(to_number(secondid, '99G999D9S'))+1,2,4) from table";`

#### *The components:*

`'99G999D9S'`
A format specificer: 2 digits + group separator + 3 digits + decimal point + 1 digit + sign.

`to_number(secondid, '99G999D9S')`
Convert the secondid field to a number using the above format.

`max(...)`
Standard SQL max function.

`10000+max(...)+1`
Add 10,001 to the results of max.

`substr(...,2,4)`
Extract 4 characters from the results of the previous, starting at char position 2.

`SC || substr(...)`
Concatenate the string from above with `SC`.

Comment: I see, thanks, the actual stuff done by the line is clearer now.